# Does Social Media Website like facebook,Instagram, Foursquare and Youtube provide Real time notification when content deleted from these website

Tags: facebook, youtube, foursquare, instagram

I am working on social media website and putting there real time updates in our database. But problem is when user delete the image or vedio from instagram or other social media website then we are unable to show these content because we dont save image or vidio on our server.

We can handle this problem by handle if we are able to remove content from our server when user would delete data from social media website.For this we need callback notification to delete this content from our server too.

My question is does  facebook,Instagram, Foursquare and Youtube support realtime notification when user delete own data on these social websites.

Comment: Have you found a way to get updates when someone deletes content from Instagram?

Comment: For some reason I have switched to another urgent project so I had not searched further and didnt get answer till date.